# Modal box selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

When I click on the login in www.snaptrude.com, a modal box appears, then there are email and password textboxes and a login button. I don't know how to enter text into the textboxes and click on the login button. I tried to enter text into email field.

Here's the code that I use for that

...

WebElement c = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login_username']"));

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", c);

c.sendKeys("asdfd");

...

Answer (score 0):

Why use `javascript` executor when there are `id`'s available. Try this:

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("login_username"));
username.sendKeys("YOUR_USERNAME_HERE");
WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("login_password"));
password.sendKeys("YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE");
WebElement loginbtn = driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm"));
loginbtn.click();
```

Hope it does it for you!

Comment: Email and Password fields do not get populated. and also login button is not clicking.

Comment: When you say populated, do you mean the modal is not coming up when you click on the login button?

Comment: Nope, In the email and password fields no text is getting entered. i used the code you given above.

Comment: Well I tried the above code and it entered the values. In which browser are you working? Also try putting breakpoints to see till which line your code is working fine!